# Plotting a 3D vertical plane in Julia

Tags: julia

My goal:

[image]

```
using Plots; 
gr()
x=range(-3,stop=3,length=100)
y=range(-3,stop=3,length=100)

X,Y=collect(Iterators.product(x, y))
f(x,y) = 0.5cos.(x./2).*sin.(y./2)
p(y,x) = 3

surface(X,Y,p,surftype=(surface=true, mesh=true))
```

I have tried creating a meshgrid to plot this vertical plane (seeing as it is impossible to plot vertical planes otherwise, as you can generate an explicit function for coordinate z to plot - unlike other shapes and surfaces. However, implementing this solution in Julia has proven difficult for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply looking to plot this data, you could imitate a vertical line using a very small axis range, the x axis in your example image.

You can achieve the desired plot in this way using:

```
using Plots; 
gr()

res = 10
x = y = range(-1*res,stop=res,length=10)
eps_x = range(-1*eps(),stop=eps(),length=10) #create a very small range

X = repeat(x,1,length(y))
Y = repeat(y',length(x),1)

all_zeroes = X .* 0

plot(xlabel = "X", ylabel = "Y", zlabel = "Z", xrange = (-1*res,res), yrange = (-1*res,res), zrange = (-1*res,res)) #create empty 3d plot

surface!(x,y,all_zeroes, surftype=(surface = true, mesh = true)) #create horizontal plane
surface!(eps_x,y,Y, surftype=(surface = true, mesh = true)) #create "verticle" plane
```

Keep in mind that gr() doesn't do great with overlapping surfaces, even using wireframe!() instead of surface!()

[image]